# Create a PHP page to refresh the permalink on a custom table

Tags: permalinks

I need to access the permalink of every post, I can achieve this task by creating a template page as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24356000/196210) but it looks like a dirty solution for me.

How can I write a slim PHP which start the Wordpress Engine without having to create a Page inside WordPress?

Comment: Have you considered using WP CLI? the `wp post` subcommands are capable of doing this, and it'll run faster than a page template. Otherwise your approach is fundamentally limited by the PHP execution time limit when doing it via a browser. Doing it in the terminal with WP CLI has no such limit, and much higher memory limits

Comment: It might also be possible to do this with the REST API by requesting every page or the posts endpoint, ideally any answer using the REST API would provide an example

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304926/how-to-include-wordpress-functions-in-custom-php-file but I will also read about WP CLI